# Magento 2 : How quickly can you install with composer a Magento2 last version without sample data

Tags: magento2, installation, composer, sample-data

How quickly can you install with composer a Magento2 last version without sample data

Comment: Very quick... http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run command to bring Magento2 from the repository:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento
```

add the credential for Username and Password for authentification on the terminal, your credential is in your Magento.com account after you logged in click [here](https://marketplace.magento.com/customer/accessKeys/).

---

After ruling the composer command you have to enter in the Magento folder that was created by the composer

```
cd magento
```

Create the database and completes below with the following command:
database name, database user, database password, domain, First Name, Last Name, Email address, user admin, admin password, admin path

Then rule the command for install Magento2 in terminal:

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://domain.com/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=db_name --db-user=db_user --db-password=db_pass --admin-firstname=FirstName --admin-lastname=LastName --admin-email=email@domain.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=password --language=en_US --backend-frontname=admin --magento-init-params=“MAGE_MODE=developer”
```

---

And now you can enjoy Magento2.