# Magento 2 installation from GitHub: blank screen

Tags: magento2, installation, server-setup

I have been trying for days to install Magento 2 on a Vagrant box running
Ubuntu, Nginx & PHP 7.0.13

When I try to load the setup/installtion wizard I get a blank screen with no errors in the console or Nginx log

[image: Setup page]

Does anyone know what the correct steps are or what is causing this to happen?

If I try to install via php bin/magento setup:install

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://magento.dev/ \
--backend-frontname=admin \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento2 --db-user=root --db-password=root \
--admin-firstname=Test --admin-lastname=Test—admin-email=email@email.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=password --language=en_GB \
--currency=GBP --timezone=Europe/London --use-rewrites=1
```

I get the following error

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]   
  Parameter validation failed
```

If I try with the command on one line I get the same error:

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://mage.dev --backend-frontname=admin --db-name=magento2 --db-user=root --db-password=magento2 --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1

  [InvalidArgumentException]   
  Parameter validation failed
```

What is this error and do I fix it?
Why is it so difficult install Magento 2?

** UPDATE **
I've reinstalled from [Magento 2 Repo](https://github.com/magento/magento2) Instead of using the .zip archive
but now I get the following screen
[image]

When I try to debug the request flow it looks to me like the classMap isn't getting the correct path when trying to autoload:

`/home/vagrant/www/./vendor/autoload.php`

Comment: Have you install on localhost on your pc or directly in server

Comment: I'm using vagrant, I have the files on the server and mounted on my mac

Comment: The vendor autoload looks wrong to me `/home/vagrant/www/./vendor/autoload.php`

Comment: try with, php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://<host or ip>/<your Magento install dir>/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento2 --db-user=root --db-password=magento2 --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1

Comment: Doesn't work `[InvalidArgumentException]   
  Parameter validation failed ` I always get this error

Comment: please check your base-url,  --base-url=http://<host or ip>/<your Magento install dir>/ and keep / at last of base url. just try with this

Comment: `php bin/magento setup:install --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=root --db-password=root --backend-frontname=admin --admin-user=test --admin-password=test --admin-email=test@test --admin-firstname=test --admin-lastname=test --base-url=http://magento2.dev/ --language=en_US --currency=USD --use-rewrites=1 --use-secure=0 --use-secure-admin=0 --cleanup-database
`

Comment: I have the file directly under my `www` folder

Comment: Try this:
<br/>
Magento install without sample data -> [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144111/how-quickly-can-you-install-with-composer-a-magento2-last-version-without-sample/144112#144112)
<br/>
Magento install with sample data -> [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144571/how-quickly-can-you-install-a-magento2-last-version-with-sample-data-with-compos/144572#144572)

Comment: Check files permissions.
(for testing you can set 777 to all magento files)

Comment: Please add  `-vvv` to cli and post trace here.
Also, can you use a different domain that does not have `.dev` at the end

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but try the following version of composer install:

```
php bin/magento setup:install --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user= --db-password= --backend-frontname= --admin-user= --admin-password= --admin-email= --admin-firstname= --admin-lastname= --base-url= --language=en_US --currency=USD --use-rewrites=1 --use-secure=0 --use-secure-admin=0 --cleanup-database
```

fill the information needed after the each = in the composer command, this worked for me

Comment: Hi same as below, ` [InvalidArgumentException]   
  Parameter validation failed `

Comment: Did you clone the magento2 repo or you downloaded the archive? If you cloned the repository be sure to run "composer install" before trying to install magento itself, after this your webinstaller should work. I installed magento2 for more than 10 times and worked as a charm

Answer (score 3):

When you downloaded from git I've found troubles with the master branch. Download the last stable version (2.2.2) branch instead and try that

Answer (score 1):

I know Vagrant used to cause some issues when dealing with several lines as you can see from this commit: https://github.com/boostmyshoporganization/vagrant-magento2/commit/526119804cc175317771de4492c6974e3f4925a5

I suggest you run this command on one single line.

Comment: Did try that but get the same error `  [InvalidArgumentException]   
  Parameter validation failed `

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure you have redirects enabled and allowed on nginx. You can add this by putting the following in your server block in the vhost:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Ehm... isn't this an apache directive?

Comment: You'd be right! My mistake! I think I was sat in Apache configs all that day!

Comment: On the plus side if the user decides to ditch nginx and go apache, he/she'll have an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that when installing Magento 2 on a nginx server you have to include the `index.php` to the URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/setup/index.php
```

I believe I've read somewhere that this is currently a bug in the installer.