# Changing from a git to a composer installation

Tags: magento2, composer, git

I'm afraid, I've got a Magento 2 installation which has been done via git. I'm not a developer and would like to upgrade simply via composer update.

Is it somehow possible to move or migrate from one installation/method to the other?

Some more details:
Currently running on 2.1.9
Two extensions installed
Would like to upgrade to 2.2.4

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

1) Backup your Database and Magento Root Directory.

2) Installed A clean installation of the version of Magento 2 you are using (important)
Use these links as reference to installing Magento 2 using composer:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/composer.html
- https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-2-composer/

3) Make sure clean installation is successful.

4) Delete the clean installation DB and Import backup DB

5) This step is for sites that already have content. Override some of the content of the clean installation with the content of the Magento Root Directory. Use the list below:

- (Magento Root Directory)/app/design/frontend/(Your themes)/ (Note:
  only your themes, not the Magento theme unless you overrode anything)
- (Magento Root Directory)/pub/media/ (Note: Make sure this you
  carefully select the right folders)

The list might change depending on your extensions and customization.

6) Make sure your site is in developer mode. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html

7) Finally, run 
php bin/magento cache:flush && php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

This should get you moved to a composer installation
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Magento root and apply bellow commands

> ```
> step -1 :composer require Magento/product-community-edition 2.2.4 --no-update
> step -2 :composer update (Need private and public key for update composer)
> step -3 :-rm -rf var/
> step -4 :-php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> step -5 :-php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
> step -6 :-chmod -R 777 ../mage2/
> ```

Comment: It seems a "git Magento" can't be updated in a "composer way" - that's why I asked.
One will receive this message: - The requested package magento/product-community-edition could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Comment: [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find a matching version of package magento/product-community-edition. Check the package spelling
  , your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stab
  ility (alpha).


Does not work.