# Magento 2.2 is not Installing i have VPS

Tags: magento2, php, installation, version

i have vps server from godaddy.
i tried to install magento it gives me error. i also fulfilled all magento requirements by easyapache4.. 
With PHP7, Magento 2 require these PHP extensions on server:

```
bc-math
curl
gd, ImageMagick 6.3.7 (or later) or both
intl
PDO/MySQL
SimpleXML
soap
xml
xsl
zipmbstring
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
OpenSSL
```

still, when I install Magento it gives me following error. even when I have uploaded copy of Magento from its official website. after extract, it doesn't let me go through the installation process.

[image: error image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommended installing **Magento2** from the terminal because is really safe.

Below, you have two posts (with / without sample data) about how can you install **Magento2** from the terminal,

[Magento 2 : How can you install a Magento2 quickly to last version with sample data with composer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144571/magento-2-how-can-you-install-a-magento2-quickly-to-last-version-with-sample-d/144572#144572)

[Magento 2 : How quickly can you install with composer a Magento2 last version without sample data](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144111/magento-2-how-quickly-can-you-install-with-composer-a-magento2-last-version-wi/144112#144112)